# Automated Account Generation Notification in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, account

I have a Master account with multiple sub-accounts in AWS. I want to get a notification whenever a new sub-account is created. How can I implement this, please?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a trail in CloudTrail, forward the logs to CloudWatch logs and create alarm for "CreateAccount" event. More details and sample filters are here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_monitoring.html

http://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudwatch-alarms-for-cloudtrail.html